# display formatted string on JPanel

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jlabel

I have a method which returns a string that is formatted like so:

```
myString += "1. Hello\n" +
            "2. Goodbye\n";
```

I am attempting to display it as a JLabel but it is coming out

```
1. Hello 2. Goodbye
```

Is there a way to display the string with the newlines besides formatting it with HTML or is there another outlet to display the information correctly besides JLabel?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1842223/java-linebreaks-in-jlabels

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For list data, use a [`JList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) instead.

If this really is textual data, use a (noneditable) [`JTextArea`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html).