# linebreaks in output

Tags: java, swing, output

I'm building a program that receives an input string with linebreaks through a GUI, splits it in lines, then in words, and then passes it word by word to a method I still have to implement, `translate`, which will somehow take a word and swap it with an appropriate one. At the moment, with the following code:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author michelegorini
 */
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout;
import javax.swing.LayoutStyle;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
public class HakkaTranslator extends JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form HakkaTranslator
     */
    public HakkaTranslator() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">//GEN-BEGIN:initComponents
    private void initComponents() {

        inputField = new JTextArea();
        translateButton = new JButton();
        pinyinField = new JLabel();
        hakkaCharField = new JLabel();
        mandCharField = new JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        translateButton.setText("Translate");
        translateButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {

                inpText = inputField.getText();
                String[] lines = inpText.split(System.lineSeparator());
                String[][] words = new String[lines.length][20];
                for(int i=0;i<lines.length;i++){
                    words[i] = lines[i].split(" ");
                }
                for(int i=0;i<lines.length;i++){
                    for(int j = 0;j<words[i].length;j++){
                        translate(words[i][j]);
                    }
                    translate(System.lineSeparator());
                }
            }
        });

        GroupLayout layout = new GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(hakkaCharField, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 282, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(mandCharField, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 216, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                            .addComponent(translateButton, GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(inputField, GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 252, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                        .addPreferredGap(LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(pinyinField, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 282, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        layout.linkSize(SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL, new java.awt.Component[] {hakkaCharField, inputField, mandCharField, pinyinField});

        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(translateButton)
                .addPreferredGap(LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addComponent(pinyinField, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(inputField, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 165, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addPreferredGap(LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(hakkaCharField, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 136, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(mandCharField))
                .addContainerGap(177, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        layout.linkSize(SwingConstants.VERTICAL, new java.awt.Component[] {hakkaCharField, inputField, mandCharField, pinyinField});

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>//GEN-END:initComponents

    private void translate(String word) {
        pinyinField.setText(pinyinField.getText() + word + " ");
    }
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(HakkaTranslator.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(HakkaTranslator.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(HakkaTranslator.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(HakkaTranslator.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new HakkaTranslator().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify//GEN-BEGIN:variables
    private JLabel hakkaCharField;
    private JTextArea inputField;
    private JLabel mandCharField;
    private JLabel pinyinField;
    private JButton translateButton;
    // End of variables declaration//GEN-END:variables
    String inpText;
}
```

I have gotten practically everything working, save for the `translate` method, which is the next step, and for the fact that, whether I put `System.lineSeparator()` or `"\n"` as the argument in the line `translate(System.lineSeparator())`, the result is invariably a wide space, while I want a linebreak. How do I make the linebreak appear in the output?

I'd post an image but I don't have enough reputation. Please note that I've just tried putting `""<html><br/></html>""` instead of `System.lineSeparator()`, in light of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1842223/java-linebreaks-in-jlabels), but that didn't work either. I remember trying the `MultiLineUI` answer's command and getting a `cannot find symbol` or the likes.

Comment: post the image and we'll edit it so it appears. Just provide the link of the image

Comment: Could you shortly explain _what you want_ to do? Maybe there is a different solution than adding the text from the JTextArea to the JLabel?

Comment: My idea is to subsequently implement a method that substitutes the words with their Hakka Ideograms, Mandarin translation Ideograms and corresponding Pinyin, for which the three labels are present. I will look into SQL to avoid writing an infinite sequence of `if`s and `elses`. The following step, though with my abilities it seems very ambitious, maybe too ambitious, is to develop a Google Translate-like interface that highlights single words in the labels when the mouse is passed over them and reveals a list of other translations when you click on the words.

Comment: But I might be contented with adding a fifth label to print the lists of translations for words with multiple translations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {

        inpText = inputField.getText();
        String[] lines = inpText.split("\n");
        String[][] words = new String[lines.length][20];
        for(int i=0;i<lines.length;i++){
            words[i] = lines[i].split(" ");
        }
        translate("<html>");
        for(int i=0;i<lines.length;i++){
            for(int j = 0;j<words[i].length;j++){
                translate(words[i][j] );
            }
            translate("<br/>");
        }
        translate("</html>");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use `<pre></pre>` around your stuff, then the html renderer will treat it as pre-formatted. You can also try to just add `</br>\n` without the HTML tags your output line separator.   I believe Swing takes text, but expects it to be HTML.